# How can I deploy GitLab pages in a subdirectory?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I have a repo like this:

- App // app source code
- Website // website source code, where my
  GitLab pages are

What I'd like is when i run .gitlab-ci.yml, it deploys all the files in the Website directory. Right now, I get errors when it tries to deploy. How can I achieve this?
This is my current .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: ruby:2.3

variables:
  JEKYLL_ENV: production

before_script:
  - bundle install

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - test
  except:
    - master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this:

```
publish: path/to/your/folder
```

under the page entry like below:

```
pages:
    publish: path/to/your/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

A directory called "public" in your site's repo is a requisite for working with pages: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html